# Stop Video on Close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing issue when i click close button in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.Actually I've created a video player with image thumbnails,when i click any image it opens video in a popup window but when i click close button it still keep playing video in the background,this issue is occuring in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome

```
<!-- ################################ VIDEO ########################## -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bodywrapper").css("display", "none");

    $("#show-panel").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper").css("display", "block");
    });

    $("a#show-panel").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper").css("display", "block");
        $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(600);
    })
    $("#bodywrapper").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper").css("display", "none");
        $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);

    })

    $("a#close-panel").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper").css("display", "none");
        $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);

    })
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bodywrapper2").css("display", "none");

    $("#show-panel2").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper2").css("display", "block");
    });

    $("a#show-panel2").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper2").css("display", "block");
        $("#lightbox2, #lightbox-panel2").fadeIn(600);
    })
    $("#bodywrapper2").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper2").css("display", "none");
        $("#lightbox2, #lightbox-panel2").fadeOut(300);

    })

    $("a#close-panel2").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper2").css("display", "none");
        $("#player").attr('src', '');
        $("#lightbox2, #lightbox-panel2").fadeOut(300);

    })
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bodywrapper3").css("display", "none");

    $("#show-panel3").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper3").css("display", "block");
    });

    $("a#show-panel3").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper3").css("display", "block");
        $("#lightbox3, #lightbox-panel3").fadeIn(600);
    })
    $("#bodywrapper3").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper3").css("display", "none");
        $("#lightbox3, #lightbox-panel3").fadeOut(300);

    })

    $("a#close-panel3").click(function () {
        $("#bodywrapper3").css("display", "none");
        $("#lightbox3, #lightbox-panel3").fadeOut(300);

    })
})
</script>
```

html

```
    <ul  id="videos" >
<li>
<a id="show-panel" href="#"><img src="images/mediapic1.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px"  alt=""/></a>
<div id="bodywrapper"></div> <!--black env-->
<div id="lightbox-panel">
<a id="close-panel" href="#"></a>
<!-- This version of the embed code is no longer supported. Learn more: https://vimeo.com/s/tnm --> <object width="498" height="280"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=60432002&amp;force_embed=1&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=e2fb2e&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=60432002&amp;force_embed=1&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=e2fb2e&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="498" height="280"></embed></object>
</div>
<a id="show-panel" href="#">test 1<br />
(Vimeo)</a></li>
<li>
<a id="show-panel2" href="#"><img src="images/mediapic2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px"  alt=""/></a>
<div id="bodywrapper2"></div> <!--black env-->
<div id="lightbox-panel2">
<a id="close-panel2" href="#"></a>
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xxagyv" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
<a id="show-panel2" href="#">test 2<br />
(Dailymotion)</a>
</li>

<li>
<a id="show-panel3" href="#"><img src="images/mediapic3.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px"  alt=""/></a>
<div id="bodywrapper3"></div> <!--black env-->
<div id="lightbox-panel3">
<a id="close-panel3" href="#"></a>
<object width="410" height="341" id="veohFlashPlayer" name="veohFlashPlayer"><param name="movie" value="http://www.veoh.com/swf/webplayer/WebPlayer.swf?version=AFrontend.5.7.0.1445&permalinkId=v69827353hY7P87kc&player=videodetailsembedded&videoAutoPlay=0&id=anonymous"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.veoh.com/swf/webplayer/WebPlayer.swf?version=AFrontend.5.7.0.1445&permalinkId=v69827353hY7P87kc&player=videodetailsembedded&videoAutoPlay=0&id=anonymous" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="410" height="341" id="veohFlashPlayerEmbed" name="veohFlashPlayerEmbed"></embed></object>
</div>
<a id="show-panel3" href="#">test 3<br />
(Veoh)</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you forget the html

Comment: @Himanshu: What should he get from another not-yet-answered question!?

Comment: for flash video [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?75553-Start-Stop-Buttons-for-Flash-(-swf)-video-working-in-all-browsers-but-IE)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better not to use embeds and flash  tags, and instead use a well-known jQuery plugin to let it handle the commands to your players.

one great example is the jquery-video plugin: https://github.com/dachcom-digital/jquery-video

from the official page:

> Unifies the iframe APIs of Youtube, Vimeo and Dailymotion. Build as
> responsive jQuery UI widget.

**Features**

> - Play, Pause and Stop command for Youtube, Vimeo and Dailymotion Player
> - supports >=IE8, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera Responsive with CSS
> - inspired by
>   http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

an example can be found via this link: http://jquery-video.dachcom.ch/demo/

**Update**

if for any reason you can't use a jquery-plugin or that you need to target the embedded player by your own code, you can utilize the official JS API for each provider that you expect your content to come from.

for example:

- Vimeo => https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript
- Youtube => https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
- Dailymotion => http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html

Comment: Can't i do something in my functions to stop playing a video when clicking button whose event is written as i mentioned.

Comment: you can, but you will need to target each provider API by your own (youtube, vimeo, dailymotion). if I were you, I would go and use the mentioned plugin, why can't you use it anyway? :)

Comment: if i am using single site videos let's say vidoes from daily motion then how do i achieve what i mentioned above

Comment: check my updated section above, you will find the official JS for Dailymotion player, which will enable you to control the player via JS.

Comment: look it's working now but only problem is it's not working in Internet Explorer 8,other versions of IE are working fine